# Dynamically changed value in jQuery not seen in sent jsp form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am submitting the form on click button, but whatever I have changed that data is not sent but the previous data is sent, is there a way in which I can commit the data of the field in forms then send??

```
$j("body").on('click', "#btn_snd",function(){
     Retrieve_Property_name();
         $j(this).closest("form").submit();
         });
});
```

The changes are done using ajax

```
function Retrieve_Property_name()
{ 
    $j(".class_cat").hide();
    var property_name = $j("#property_name").val();
    $j.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "ShowCat.jsp",
          data : "property_name=" + property_name ,
          success : function(data) {
              if(data.trim()=="No")
              {
                  $j("#Cat_name_hidden").val("General");
                  alert("Inside No");
              }     
              else if(data.trim()=="Yes")
              {
                  alert("Inside yes");
                  if($j("#Cat_name").val()==null)
                  {
                      $j("#Cat_name_hidden").val(" NULL");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      //
                      alert("Categories:-"+$j("#Cat_name").val());
                      $j("#Cat_name_hidden").val($j("#Cat_name").val());
                      //
                      arr1 = $j("#Cat_name").val();
                  }

                  $j(".class_cat").show();
              }
              alert();
         }
     });
}
```

This is the change function

Comment: what does `Change_Functions();` do ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, what is meant by `I have changed that data is not sent but the previous data is sent` ... Is the data in from is prepopulated.

Comment: if i remove the .submit () and submit using another button, the changed data goes.

Comment: multiple pages? Show cat is a single pages which sends data=yes/no

Comment: sorry its forms , i meant do you have mulitple forms in your jsp ?.

Comment: the changes to the hidden test can be viewed in the current page at the last blank alert, but the getParameter() function shows the previous val.

Comment: ya there are 2 forms

Comment: No use, there is a problem wit the ajax i think but cant figure it out.

Comment: The changes are done inside ajax , is this the reason it is not reflected at the very instance?

Comment: @SanKrish when i make the change outsite ajax inside the same function it is reflected, so my doubt was right, but i want to knw the reason y is it not reflected, and how to commit the changes.

Comment: What response do u get in ur ajax function..??

Comment: Yes/No is the value of data variable.

Comment: can u guyz upvote my question so that it can be solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the `submit` function from the `on` function:

```
$j(this).closest("form").submit();
```

can you do this after your ajax call completes within the `success` function:

```
$j("#btn_snd").closest("form").submit();
```

My guess is that the form gets submitted before the ajax request completes and hence the old values are posted. So ideally the change function would be:

```
function Retrieve_Property_name()
{ 
    $j(".class_cat").hide();
    var property_name=$j("#property_name").val();
     $j.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : "ShowCat.jsp",
         data : "property_name=" + property_name ,
         success : function(data) {
            if(data.trim()=="No")
            {
                $j("#Cat_name_hidden").val("General");
                alert("Inside No");
            }   
            else if(data.trim()=="Yes")
            {
                 alert("Inside yes");

                 if($j("#Cat_name").val()==null)
                 {
                     $j("#Cat_name_hidden").val(" NULL");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //
                     alert("Categories:-"+$j("#Cat_name").val());
                     $j("#Cat_name_hidden").val($j("#Cat_name").val());
                     //
                     arr1 = $j("#Cat_name").val();
                 }

                 $j(".class_cat").show();
            }

            alert();
            $j("#btn_snd").closest("form").submit();
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: That was sm solution, can u tell me tough why is the page sent before the ajax calls?

Comment: Or il put this way, y is the ajax fuction alwaz executed last?

Comment: Ajax function sends a request to the server and hence there would be a time consumed to get the response. But you were invoking `$j(this).closest("form").submit();` just after the ajax call which does not guarantee that the request has completed. It can be only guaranteed within the `success` function of ajax call.